# How to define where in ORMLite without queryBuilder

Tags: java, android, database, ormlite

When using ORMLite is possible to define Where object without queryBuilder? I would like to define a lot of where queries, and to apply my constraints later, when get queryBuilder of db.

So, I will have something like this. First create the queries:

```
    ...
    myQ1 = new MyQuery ({something}...where.ge("Date", lowValue).and().le("Date", hiValue))
    myQ2 = new MyQuery ({something}...where.eq("Date", dateValue))
    ...
```

where

```
public class MyQuery {
    Where where;

    // Constructor
    public MyQuery1 (Where dbWhere) {
        this.where = dbWhere;
    }
...
```

so depending on my criteria I can later call a different queries: myQ1, or myQ2:

```
    QueryBuilder<Object, String> queryBuilder = dao.queryBuilder();

    Where mainWhere = queryBuilder.where();

    ...case....
        mainWhere.add(myQ1.where);
    ...
        mainWhere.add(myQ2.where);

...
```

So, my question is how to write correctly:

```
new MyQuery1 ( /* something... */
    where.ge("Date", lowValue).and().le("Date", hiValue))
```

all other parts already work. If I try `new Where()` it requires a queryBuilder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ofcourse you can, it will work like this:

```
    Where<YourClass, YourId> where = qB.where();
    where.and(firstWhere, secondWhere, otherWheres)
    qB.setWhere(where)
```

But note that you can't create `Where` without `queryBuilder` instance

Comment: Hi, Actualy I wanted to create without queryBuilder instance.